# How to replace all non whitespace characters except one (semicolon)?

Tags: regex, perl

I have following regex in perl for replacing all continuous non-whitespace characters

```
perl -p -i.bak -e 's/^set gamma=\S*/set gamma=GAMMA/' tmp;
```

If the `tmp` file contains `set gamma=sdjfskdf; #comment` then I want to preserve the semicolon along with the comment. But using `\S*` deletes `sdjfskdf;`.

What change should I make to the regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `s/^set gamma=[^;\s]*/set gamma=GAMMA/`

Answer (score 2):

In your expression you can replace `\S*` with `[^\s;]*`, which doesn't match spaces nor `;`.